# R - is there a function similar to list.dirs which returns a named nested list instead of the character vector?

Tags: r

First let's run this function to create the example folder structure:

```
c("Level1/Level1A/Level1AA", 
  "Level1/Level1A/Level1AB", 
  "Level1/Level1B/Level1BA", 
  "Level1/Level1B/Level1BB",
  "Level2/Level2A/Level2AA", 
  "Level2/Level2A/Level2AB", 
  "Level2/Level2B/Level2BA", 
  "Level2/Level2B/Level2BB") %>% 
  map(dir.create, recursive = T)
```

Now let's imagine that this folder structure wasn't created by R but given to us as is.

If I run `list.dirs` on the parent folder, I will get:

```
 [1] "."                         "./Level1"                  "./Level1/Level1A"          "./Level1/Level1A/Level1AA" "./Level1/Level1A/Level1AB"
 [6] "./Level1/Level1B"          "./Level1/Level1B/Level1BA" "./Level1/Level1B/Level1BB" "./Level2"                  "./Level2/Level2A"         
[11] "./Level2/Level2A/Level2AA" "./Level2/Level2A/Level2AB" "./Level2/Level2B"          "./Level2/Level2B/Level2BA" "./Level2/Level2B/Level2BB"
```

However, instead of this character vector, I wish to get a named nested list like this:

```
list(Level1 = list(Level1A = list("Level1AA",
                                  "Level1AB"),
                   Level1B = list("Level1BA",
                                  "Level1BB")),
     Level2 = list(Level2A = list("Level2AA",
                                  "Level2AB"),
                   Level2B = list("Level2BA",
                                  "Level2BB")))
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion in base R as follows:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  ssplit <- function(x){
    if(is.data.frame(x))
      if(ncol(x)>1) c(by(x[-1], x[1], ssplit)) else as.list(x[[1]])
    else lapply(x, ssplit)
  }
  x <- grep("/", sub("^\\W+", "", x), value = TRUE)
  ssplit(read.table(text = x, sep='/', fill = TRUE, header = FALSE))
}

s <- c("Level1/Level1A/Level1AA", "Level1/Level1A/Level1AB", 
           "Level1/Level1B/Level1BA", "Level1/Level1B/Level1BB", "Level2/Level2A/Level2AA", 
           "Level2/Level2A/Level2AB", "Level2/Level2B/Level2BA",  "Level2/Level2B/Level2BB")

    my_fun(s)

$Level1
$Level1$Level1A
$Level1$Level1A[[1]]
[1] "Level1AA"

$Level1$Level1A[[2]]
[1] "Level1AB"


$Level1$Level1B
$Level1$Level1B[[1]]
[1] "Level1BA"

$Level1$Level1B[[2]]
[1] "Level1BB"



$Level2
$Level2$Level2A
$Level2$Level2A[[1]]
[1] "Level2AA"

$Level2$Level2A[[2]]
[1] "Level2AB"


$Level2$Level2B
$Level2$Level2B[[1]]
[1] "Level2BA"

$Level2$Level2B[[2]]
[1] "Level2BB"
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I am trying to understand how exactly does the code work, but I am having some trouble. Would you mind to answer the following questions: 1) Why do we need the part where we check if `x` is a data frame? 2) At several places in the code, the `ssplit` function refers to itself, e.g. `else lapply(x, ssplit)` - I don't understand how this works - how can some `ssplit` operation be performed on `x` if `ssplit` is yet undefined at that point?

Comment: @J.Doe I edited the code. Note that I stated we can use `recursion`. It is a fancier/easier way of logically expressing the while loop in a case where readability is prefered **. For example, we know that `factorial(n) = n * factorial(n-1)`. so `fact <- function(n) if(n==1)1 else n * fact(n-1)` will be the function. Please google more about recursion

Comment: @J.Doe the checking of a dataframe is because I read the string to dataframe, You could use other formats. That is the format I chose to use. Note that this is not the only way to write the code